# Access wordpress website on localhost from remote network

Tags: wordpress, localhost, portforwarding

I want to show my client the WordPress website on localhost being developed by me (it's still in the beginning stage, not ready to go live yet). This is what I have done so far:
- I have done port forwarding and have tested it (whenever I access my Xampp localhost from the remote network by entering my computer's ip, it opens up the localhost dashboard).

Now this where I'm stuck:
- Whenever, I specify a directory of website (in htdocs) on my remote network's url (like this: mycomputer's ip/folder's name it changes the url to localhost/folder's name and the page doesn't open).

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your wp-config.php might help:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://your-computer-IP');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-computer-IP');
```

and comment or delete that line when your work from home.

But there's something can be improved. Try to some DDNS services and install their application to your local machine. After installed, you can access your computer from `mymachine.ddns.net` even you're home or not. So with below setting, you no need to edit anything when you change your work location.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mymachine.ddns.net');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mymachine.ddns.net');
```